# How implementation my wants with MySQL JOIN

Tags: mysql

_

Hello everyone!

I have table

```
CREATE TABLE `labels` (
  `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `before_score` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And I Have This Table

```
CREATE TABLE `scores` (
  `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_id` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And i want have result where **labels.score** - have value last **scores.score** sorted by **scores.date** and **labels.before_score** where have value penultimate **scores.score** sorted by **scores.date**. Can I do This Only on Mysql slq and how?

Thanks.

**ADD**

For example i have this data on first table:

```
INSERT INTO `labels` (id, name, score, before_score) VALUES (1, 'John', 200, 123);
INSERT INTO `labels` (id, name, score, before_score) VALUES (2, 'Eddie', 2000, 2000);
INSERT INTO `labels` (id, name, score, before_score) VALUES (3, 'Bob', 400, 3101);
```

And second table

```
INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`,`name_id`,`score`,`date`) VALUES ('1','1','12','2013-07-10');
INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`,`name_id`,`score`,`date`) VALUES ('2','2','2000','2013-05-04');
INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`,`name_id`,`score`,`date`) VALUES ('3','3','654','2012-09-12');
INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`,`name_id`,`score`,`date`) VALUES ('4','1','123','2013-12-17');
INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`,`name_id`,`score`,`date`) VALUES ('5','1','200','2014-04-25');
INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`,`name_id`,`score`,`date`) VALUES ('6','3','3101','2013-12-02');
INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`,`name_id`,`score`,`date`) VALUES ('6','2','2000','2015-12-02');
INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`,`name_id`,`score`,`date`) VALUES ('6','3','400','2013-12-02');
```

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are looking for. Please post a sample from each table, and a sample of the result you would expect it to produce.

Comment: Sorry.. I add example, i hope that you understand what i want.

Comment: You don't need to store the score in the `labels` table, because you are storing it in the `scores` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the last *two* scores for each `name_id`.

I would tackle this with temporary tables:

**Step 1.** Last score:

```
create temporary table temp_score1
    select name_id, max(`date`) as lastDate
    from scores
    group by name_id;
-- Add the appropriate indexes 
alter table temp_score1
    add unique index idx_name_id(name_id),
    add index idx_lastDate(lastDate);
```

**Step 2.** Penultimate score. The idea is exactly the same, but using `temp_score1` to filter the data:

```
create temporary table temp_score2
    select s.name_id, max(`date`) as penultimateDate
    from scores as s
        inner join temp_score1 as t on s.nameId = t.nameId
    where s.`date` < t.lastDate
    group by name_id;
-- Add the appropriate indexes
alter table temp_score2
    add unique index idx_name_id(name_id),
    add index idx_penultimateDate(penultimateDate);
```

**Step 3.** Put it all together.

```
select 
    l.id, l.name,
    s1.lastScore, s2.penultimateScore
from
    `labels` as l
    left join temp_score1 as s1 on l.id = s1.name_id
    left join temp_score2 as s2 on l.id = s2.name_id
```

You can put this three steps inside a stored procedure.

Hope this helps you.